# Angular Validators not Triggering with Data Binding

Tags: angular, typescript

Im using a Max Validator on a input type Number field in my angular aplication, however i have this input value binding with a plus and minus butons that increment and decresed the value of the input, this is working as expected but if i change the value of the input using this buttons my input validators are never trigger

i want the validator to trigger if the value goes beyond 6 but unles i type the number in the input the validators are not firing, how can i fire the input validators every time i clic the plus or minus buttons

This is my input:

```
<div class="input-group">
                  <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="minusNin()" type="button">
                      <i class="fa fa-minus">
                      </i>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                  <input
                  type="number"
                  max="6"
                  class="input-group form-control form-control-lg form-control-solid text-center" placeholder=""
                    name="ninos"
                    [value]="quantityNin"
                    value={{huesped.ninos}}
                    formControlName="ninos"
                    [class.is-invalid]="isControlInvalid('ninos')"
                    [class.is-valid]="isControlValid('ninos')"
                    >
                  <div
                    class="invalid-feedback"
                    *ngIf="controlHasError('maxlength', 'ninos')"
                  >
                    Max {{max}}
                  </div>
                  <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="plusNin()" type="button">
                      <i class="fa fa-plus">
                      </i>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

and this is my login for the buttons on the .ts file

```
plusNin()
  {
    if(this.quantityNin<6)
    {
      this.quantityNin++;
      this.huesped.ninos=this.quantityNin;
    }
  }
  minusNin()
  {
    if(this.quantityNin>1)
    {
    this.quantityNin--;
    this.huesped.ninos=this.quantityNin;
    }
    else
    this.quantityNin
    this.huesped.ninos=this.quantityNin;

  }
```

I have also tryed to use this function inside my plus and minus functions but this does not triggers the input validator nor the div with the message of max capacity

```
      this.formGroup.controls['ninos'].updateValueAndValidity();
```

Someone have any ideas how can i do this?

Comment: Try this    this.huesped[ 'controls'].ninos.patchValue(this.quantityNin)

Comment: cannot read property ninos of undefined are you sure this is how i invoke it'?

Comment: i tryed using this this.formGroup.controls['ninos'].patchValue(this.quantityNin) but still the patchValue method is not fired or at least it doesnt check if the input is vailidated